# Why does Saxon evaluate the result-document URI to be the same?

Tags: xslt-2.0, saxon, xslt

My XSL source document looks like this

```
<Topology>
<Environment>
    <Id>test</Id>
    <Machines>
        <Machine>
            <Id>machine1</Id>
            <modules>
                <module>m1</module>
                <module>m2</module>
            </modules>
        </Machine>
    </Machines>
</Environment>
<Environment>
    <Id>production</Id>
    <Machines>
        <Machine>
            <Id>machine1</Id>
            <modules>
                <module>m1</module>
                <module>m2</module>
            </modules>
        </Machine>
        <Machine>
            <Id>machine2</Id>
            <modules>
                <module>m3</module>
                <module>m4</module>
            </modules>
        </Machine>
    </Machines>
</Environment>
</Topology>
```

I want to create one result-document per machine, so I use the following stylesheet giving modelDir as path for the result-documents as parameter.

```
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" 
            indent="yes" name="myXML" doctype-system="http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="/Topology/Environment/Machines/Machine" group-by="Id">

        <xsl:variable name="machine" select="Id"/>
        <xsl:variable name="filename" select="concat($modelDir,$machine,'.xml')" />

        <xsl:message terminate="no">Writing machine description to <xsl:value-of select="$filename"/></xsl:message>

        <xsl:result-document href="$filename" format="myXML">

            <xsl:variable name="currentMachine" select="Id"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()/LogicalHosts/LogicalHost">
                <xsl:variable name="environment" select="normalize-space(../../../../Id)"/>
                <xsl:message terminate="no">Module <xsl:value-of select="."/> for <xsl:value-of select="$environment"/></xsl:message>
            </xsl:for-each>

        </xsl:result-document>

     </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

As my messages show me this seems to work fine - if saxon would not evaluate the URI of the result-document to be the same and thus give the following output.

```
Writing machine description to target/build/model/m1.xml
Module m1 for test
Module m2 for test
Module m1 for production
Module m2 for production
Writing machine description to target/build/model/m2.xml
Error at xsl:result-document on line 29 of file:/C:/Projekte/.../machine.xsl:
  XTDE1490: Cannot write more than one result document to the same URI, or write to a URI
  that has been read:
  file:/C:/Projekte/.../$filename
file:/C:/Projekte/.../machine.xsl(29,-1) : here Cannot write more than one result document to the same URI, or write to a URI that has been read: file:/C:/Projekte/.../$filename
; SystemID: file:/C:/Projekte/.../machine.xsl; Line#: 29; Column#: -1
net.sf.saxon.trans.DynamicError: Cannot write more than one result document to the same URI, or write to a URI that has been read: file:/C:/Projekte/.../$filename
    at net.sf.saxon.instruct.ResultDocument.processLeavingTail(ResultDocument.java:300)
    at net.sf.saxon.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:365)
    at net.sf.saxon.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:91)
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are specifying a variable `$filename` for the `@file`, but did not wrap in `{}`so it is evaluating it as the string "$filename" every time(which is the same URI, thus the error).

You need it to evaluate as an **[Attribute Value Template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates)**.

```
<xsl:result-document href="{$filename}" format="myXML">
```

Comment: Why didn't I realize that? Thank you so much for opening my blind mind ;-) Good: reference on AVT.