# Mule 3.4.2 XSLT Transformer throws Cannot write more than one result document to the same URI, or write to a URI that has been read

Tags: xml, xslt, mule, xslt-2.0

I have XML coming to a mule flow. I need to break this xml into 3 different xml and write to 3 files. This is how I call `XSLT Transformer` in mule flow.

```
    <xm:xslt-transformer xsl-file="xsl/xml-to-file.xsl">
        <xm:context-property key="A_loc" value="${location.a}" />
        <xm:context-property key="B_loc" value="${location.b}" />
        <xm:context-property key="C_loc" value="${location.c}" />
    </xm:xslt-transformer>
```

And this is how the `xsl` is defined:

`<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">`

```
<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:param name="A_loc" />
<xsl:param name="B_loc" />
<xsl:param name="C_loc" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//table[@name='A_DATA']" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//table[@name='B_DATA']" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//table[@name='C_DATA']" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="table[@name='A_DATA']">
    <xsl:result-document href="{$A_loc}" >
        <xsl:for-each select="row">
            <xsl:for-each select="field">
                .... some logic
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="table[@name='B_DATA']">
    <xsl:result-document href="{$B_loc}">
        <xsl:for-each select="row">
            <xsl:for-each select="field">
                ... some logic
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="table[@name='C_DATA']">
    <xsl:result-document href="{$C_loc}">
        <xsl:for-each select="row">
            <xsl:for-each select="field">
                ... some logic
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

This process is scheduled to run at a particular frequency. The very first time after starting server, it runs fine but all subsequent runs fail with this message

> org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy - 
>   ******************************************************************************** Message               : Cannot write more than one result document to
>   the same URI, or write to a URI that has been read:
>   file:/C:/data/local/A/Axyz.txt (net.sf.saxon.trans.DynamicError) Code 
>   : MULE_ERROR-64999
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Exception stack is:
>   1. Cannot write more than one result document to the same URI, or write to a URI that has been read:
>   file:/C:/data/local/A/Axyz.txt(net.sf.saxon.trans.DynamicError)
>   net.sf.saxon.instruct.ResultDocument:300 (null)
>   2. Cannot write more than one result document to the same URI, or write to a URI that has been read: file:/C:/data/local/A/Axyz.txt
>   (net.sf.saxon.trans.DynamicError)
>   (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException)
>   org.mule.module.xml.transformer.XsltTransformer:188
>
> ---

I checked mule is using **`saxon 8.9.0.4-osgi, saxon-dom 8.9.0.4-osgi and saxon-xqj 8.9.0.4`**

Comment: The error message looks clear enough to me - you're trying to write to the same output location more than once (e.g. if you have more than one `table` with the name `A_DATA` in the input), or to an output location that is also an input location.

Comment: Yes, I want to write to override to the same file if it exists and if don't then write to a new file. Even if after first run, I delete already created files, it throws the same error

Comment: I am trying to achieve something similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974040/why-does-saxon-evaluate-the-result-document-uri-to-be-the-same?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in Mule 3.4.2 and is addressed here.

https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-5382

Mule support provided a patch for this . Basically, they reset transformer after clearing the parameters in `XsltTransformer` file.

Answer (score 0):

`xsl:result-document` isn't designed to append nor to overwrite files. If you need to overwrite you'll have to use a component previous to your xslt to delete or backup your file prior to recreation.

Another possibility I would recommend is to abuse both the source code of the xslt transformer and Saxon's [OutputURIResolver](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.0/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/OutputURIResolver.html) but I would really trust this one.

Comment: I tried deleting previously generated file from result-document before triggering next one while running mule. It still results in same error. I'd trust Saxon as instead of using xslt-transformer when I used custom java code to transform using saxon, result-document worked as expected.

Comment: 3.6 has all the XML overhauled, perhaps you could give it a try http://blogs.mulesoft.org/mule-3-6-xml-xpath-xslt-xquery3/